# retain the value which I checked in a box in a datagridview using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Good Day to everybody.

I ran out of ideas so I'm posting this to SO, I want to create a form where users can search for records, then tik check on the datagrid view, then retain the check even though they used.

[image]

In this illustration the user searched for a certain number then selected it, its the bottom one.

I would want it that if the user would like to search for another record, the item wont be removed.

[image]

in this illustration, the item was removed because the use searched for another record.

My current work is the following

```
 Private Sub dgvConfirm_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvConfirm.CellContentClick

    If dgvConfirm.Item(0, dgvConfirm.CurrentRow.Index).Value = 0 Then
        dgvConfirm.Item(0, dgvConfirm.CurrentRow.Index).Value = 1
        nmblst = nmblst + dgvConfirm.Item(2, dgvConfirm.CurrentRow.Index).Value + ","

    Else

        dgvConfirm.Item(0, dgvConfirm.CurrentRow.Index).Value = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

this is the code when I clicked the datagridview, it just gets the unique key column and transfers it into a string.

```
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    If nmblst <> "" Or nmblst.Length > 0 Then

        nmblst = nmblst.Trim().Remove(nmblst.Length - 1)
        scndQry = " or PPFNo  in ('%" & nmblst & "%') "
    End If

    If rdoPartNo.Checked = True Then
        bndsrc.Filter = "PartNo  Like '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' " + scndQry
    Else
        bndsrc.Filter = "PPFNo  Like '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' " + scndQry
    End If

    frstQry = bndsrc.Filter

End Sub
```

This code is for searching. I am trying to use something like `select this from thistable where columnname like '%something%' and columname in (etc,etc)` do take note that `columnname` and `columnname` are the same.

Is there a property of datagridview for what I need?

Comment: I do not see how you could do this in ONE (1) `DataGridView` without “breaking” the filtering mechanism. In other words, you are going to have to do something special “outside” the filtering mechanism to allow it to “include” rows that do NOT match the grids filter. Have you considered using a second grid on the form to add the checked items to or possibly a pop-up window with a second grid showing the checked items? I am confident this will make things much easier.

Comment: @JohnG its just out of curiosity though.

Comment: Please do not think I did not attempt a solution. I have seen this before and in a lot of cases an “exotic” filter string is sometimes possible as a solution, however in this case using a “single” grid, I could not come up with a consistent way to keep the checked rows visible if they did not meet the filter criteria.

Comment: As I mentioned before, a pop-up window with a second grid appears to be not only an easier solution coding wise, but I would think this would be visually easier for the user since the “checked” rows appear “separately” from the rest of the rows. This second form would also be a convenient place to put all the necessary logic needed for the “checked” rows. Example if the checked rows represented a checkout basket the second form could have “Check Out” button, “Remove”, “Edit” etc.… Just a thought.

Comment: @JohnG That's my first design, then I saw a site with this feature and I thought if I could do the same in vb.net, it seems like its not the case.

Comment: I don’t think the language is the problem. As mentioned earlier, with “two” (2) grids, this is a piece of cake. In theory you could make your own control with two grids stacked one on top of the other however nudged close enough together that it would “appear” visually as “one” grid to the user. Obviously, maintaining this “separation” between the two grids is something the control would have to handle when checked rows are added to the top grid.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are approaching this problem incorrectly.

Assuming that only one item can be checked, try storing the checked row in a type, with each column stored separately, like this:

```
Private Type temp
    PartNo As Long
    PPFNo As Integer
    ProductNo As String
    DateCreated As DateTime
    And so on...
End Type
```

When something is checked, you find the row on which the box is checked, and then you put each field in the temp type, something like this:

```
For i = 0 to DataGridView.Columns - 1
    temp(i) = DataGridView.Item(i, selectedrow).Value
Loop
```

Then, at the end of your search, you can append your temp to the DataGridView by adding the following to your code:

```
DataGridView.Rows.Add(temp(0),temp(1),temp(2),temp(3)) 'And more if you have more columns
```

Good luck with your problem and I hope my answer helps :)

Comment: I'll be try this idea, thank you! But how about if I need to check 2 or more? Thank you!